# How does one parse the following error message from gradle ( groovy? )

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I am getting the following error message from build.gradle:

Build file '/home/nn/src/cell411/cell411-android/build.gradle' line: 18

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Cell411'.
> No signature of method: build_2viac80hv3wcdrrui885tk6hi.ext() is applicable for argument types: (build_2viac80hv3wcdrrui885tk6hi$_run_closure2) values: [build_2viac80hv3wcdrrui885tk6hi$_run_closure2@a46c943]
  Possible solutions: exec(groovy.lang.Closure), exec(org.gradle.api.Action), wait(), run(), run(), any()

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I have intentionally refrained from including the source, because I am not so much interested in how to fix the problem ( I've fixed similar before ) but understanding what it actually means.

Comment: And what is: Build file `/home/nn/src/cell411/cell411-android/build.gradle` line: 18 ??

Comment: It is an ext stanza.  I tried to add the java compatability settings to it, so I could use them like compileSdkVersion, et. el, which are already there.

I'm not sure how an ext stanza matches that message.

Is there a place where I can find one or more ext functions, and see what the prototypes are?

what the heck does the identifier "build_2viac80hv3wcdrrui885tk6hi" mean?

Are the "possible solutions" ... lists of prototypes for the ext() function?  Other things I might have done?

Comment: message saying that there is no method with name `ext` that accepts closure as input at this point.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  And I think that what the followup questions floating through my mind are telling me is "you're gonna have to bite the bullet and learn groovy".